# Flex: Positioning Plot Series item

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have a chart with multiple series (Area and Plot). The Area series has 'xField' as 'timeStamp' and 'yField' as 'price'. The Plot Series has 'xField' as 'timeStamp' and no 'yField'.... ! Can I position the plot series though I do not have a corresponding 'yField' value ? Can I assign a default value to the 'yField' (say '10' for all...?)

This is how I create my AreaChart initially. At this point, I have no idea whether to render events or not, so I do not attempt to create a 'plot series' at this point.

```
    //Note: 'AreaSeries' and 'PlotSeries' have different dataproviders
var areaChart:AreaChart = new AreaChart();
areaChart.width = width;
areaChart.height = height;
areaChart.showDataTips = true;

var vAxis:LinearAxis = new LinearAxis();
if(vAxisLblFunction != null){
    vAxis.labelFunction = vAxisLblFunction;
    areaChart.verticalAxis = vAxis;
}

var hAxis:CategoryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
hAxis.categoryField = "timeStamp";
areaChart.horizontalAxis = hAxis;
areaChart.horizontalAxisRenderer = createHAxisRenderer(hAxis);

var areaChartSeries:AreaSeries = new AreaSeries();
areaChartSeries.yField = "price";
areaChartSeries.displayName = "Stock Price";
areaChartSeries.setStyle("form", "segment");

var chartStroke:Stroke = new Stroke();
chartStroke.color = 0xFF0000;
chartStroke.weight = CHART_STROKE_WEIGHT;

var chartColor:SolidColor = new SolidColor();
chartColor.alpha = CHART_ALPHA;
chartColor.color = 0x000000;
areaChartSeries.setStyle("areaStroke", chartStroke);
areaChartSeries.setStyle("areaFill", chartColor);
chartSeriesArr.push(areaChartSeries);
```

Now, during run-time I want to plot some events as required.

```
var evtSer:PlotSeries = new PlotSeries();
evtSer.dataProvider = devEventsAC;  //Assume that I get the 'eventsDataProvider' somehow at run-time
evtSer.xField = "timeStamp";   //Notice there is no 'yField' to map here.
//evtSer.dataFunction = eventSerDataFunc;  //Tried with a 'dataFunction' assigning default value of '10' to the 'yField'

var fillColor:SolidColor = new SolidColor();
fillColor.color = 0xA933DC;
fillColor.alpha = 0.8;
evtSer.setStyle("fill", fillColor);

var strokeColor:SolidColorStroke = new SolidColorStroke();
strokeColor.color = 0x9494B8;
strokeColor.weight = 1;
evtSer.setStyle("stroke", strokeColor);
var chartSeriesArr:Array = trendPanel.areaChart.series;
chartSeriesArr.push(evtSer);
trendPanel.areaChart.series = chartSeriesArr;
```

So, my problem is that how do I plot the 'events' without a 'yField'. Is there a way to assign 'yField' value using the series's 'dataFunction' ?

Here is my thought:

1. In the 'dataFunction' we get a reference to the 'series' object. Using the series object get the 'parent' which is the chart and then get the series array for that chart.
2. Now, get the 'yField' value fron the 'AreaSeries' and return it as the 'yField' value for the 'plot series'.
3. But, if I have multiple events with same 'yField' value there is a very good chance that all the events plotted top of each other. (First I am not sure whether 1 & 2 works here...)

Second approach is using the 'CartesianDataCanvas'. Again, here it requires datapoints (x,y) which I don't have.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish.  Is it possible for you to take a screenshot or make a doodle or something to help your question?  Some code might help as well for what you've tried.

Comment: @J_A_X, did edit my question with sample code.

Comment: Using the first approach I mentioned above, I do not get the actuall 'yValue' but the 'yField' which is in this case 'price'. Kind of stuck on this ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CartesianDataCanvas](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/chartClasses/CartesianDataCanvas.html) to draw stuff on a chart using data coordinates. But if you really want to use a PlotSeries to display time events on your chart, you can loop over your dataProvider and add a property with a default value that you will use in your plotSeries as an yField...

Comment: The idea of looping through the dataProvider and add a default value seems to be an easy solution. But, that would also require adding one more 'verticalAxis' for the default values to the chart... Isn't it ?

Comment: Well I don't suppose it would : you can process the default value using the range of your AreaSeries' values, and affect the same axis to both.

Comment: Nope. It didnt work. As I mentioned in my original post, using the 'dataFunction' of the series I am returning a value of '100' for 'y'. But, nothing gets rendered.

Comment: Quick tip : to render several different series in the same chart, you would prefer to use CartesianChart instead of AreaChart. I'll try to do what you explain today.

Comment: @Loremlpsum, tried using the 'CartesianChart' instead of AreaChart, still no result. I found a way to assign corresponding 'yValue' for the plots using the 'dataFunction', but they just don't appear on the chart. The only thing I can think of is, the PlotSeries is expecting another 'Y-Axis' as the series's dataProvider is diff from 'areaSeries' dataProvider.

Comment: Here are my findings on this. Ideally we should be able to render plot series on top of area/col/bar series. The mistake I was doing was, the first time I create the chart, I am setting the 'vAxis' and 'hAxis' render based on the 'areaSeries' attributes. So, though the data was set properly for the plotseries, the plots were never getting rendered because of this. Not sure, how to format my vertical and horizontal axis values now. Should I have two axis renderers ??

Comment: You could also have two vertical axis, one for each series. Can you post your complete code (if it is possible) or put it somewhere I could download it ?